# ember testing component with yield

Tags: ember.js, qunit

I cannot get the compiled html to be inputted into the component via the `yield` block expression. See test:

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForComponent('pro-tab-link', 'Unit | Component | pro tab link', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test
  // needs: ['component:foo', 'helper:bar'],
  unit: true
});

test('it renders', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(3);

  // Creates the component instance
  var component = this.subject({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(
      "<h1>Hello world</h1>"
    )
  });

  console.log(component);
  assert.equal(component._state, 'preRender');

  var $component = this.append();

  Ember.run(function() {
   component.set('isOpen', true);
 });

  console.log(component);
  console.log($component.html());

  assert.equal(component._state, 'inDOM');
  assert.ok(component.isOpen);
});
```

And the template:

```
if isOpen
  == yield
```

For some reason, the `h1` tag is not being passed into the yield of the component. How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You should switch from unit testing your components to writing integration tests for them as per this [fantastic article](http://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/2015/06/20/ember-component-integration-tests.html) on the subject.

The reason you can't find the h1 is that this is a unit test (ie., we are ONLY testing the component.js), and we should expect not to have access to the DOM in a unit test—hence the suggestion to switch to integration testing, a level of testing higher than unit but lower than acceptance testing.

This way you will be able to test the component and its interaction with its template in the DOM.

Comment: But doesn't the docs for ember have this(finding elements with in the DOM) all over it? http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/testing/testing-components/

Comment: In the link you posted, scroll down to the part where it talks about integration test helpers. There is a line where the template is appended to the DOM.

Comment: this.append()   Until you do that there is nothing to run assertions against. And once you do that we are taking about an integration test not a unit test.

Comment: Hmm, but if you take a look at the examples in the docs, where `this.append()` is being used, `this.subject()` is used too, but `this.subject()` is not part of integration tests. I got the following error: `Error: component integration tests do not support 'subject()'.`

Comment: I think the root of the problem is still there, for some reason, `yield` is not getting a template passed to it. See these tests: https://github.com/huafu/ember.js/blob/46d3f7fbd92f704d4c274d4300db87d6c4d042bb/packages_es6/ember-handlebars/tests/helpers/yield_test.js

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas. I'll probably have to write a bunch of component tests this week. Might learn more then. I'm on 1.12, hopefully bumping up to 1.13 before then.